# how can i get rid of the close button on a jquery modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I want to have a jquery modal dialog that will have one button that will say "yes" and close the dialog. Is there any way to hide/turn off the default "Close" button or should I use another jquery element like a pop up panel? This code adds the yes button but does not turn off the close button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it using CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none;}
```

or you can init the dialog like this:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal:true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
}).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); // find and hide the button right after creating the modal
```

Also, IE doesn't like the comma after the last property of an object so remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS rule:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MkpQk/2)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
```

Just whatever you have to do to grab the item with the class "ui-dialog-titlebar-close"

Comment: where do i put $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();

Comment: Right after your call to `$("#dialog-message").dialog()` should do it.

Comment: This is throwing "unexpected token" in chrome  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();

Comment: @akh2103 After the *call*, not after that line. The call ends with the first line `});`.  Put it after that.